# Filtering out rows according to the result of a function of variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a faster way to filter out data.frame rows where, say, any three of the first 5 variables have values in a given vector. The command I used (which is very slow - the data.frame has more that 20M rows) is like that:

```
x %>%
  rowwise %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(match(c(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5),c(9,11,33,43,44))))==3 & V6!=13)
```

It seems that `rowwise` is not the best way to go. (When I tried `purrr::by_row`, it ate up all memory causing my machine to become unresponsive)

A reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- choose(45,5)
n1 <- 20*n
d <- rep(NA,n1)
y <- tibble(V1=d,V2=d,V3=d,V4=d,V5=d,V6=rep(1:20,each=n))

x1 <- t(combn(45,5))

for(i in 1:20){
  y[((i-1)*n+1):(i*n),1:5] <- x1
}

k <- sample.int(n1,21854909,replace = TRUE)
x <- y[k,]
```

Comment: can you perhaps minimze your example, i don't think we need a 20m row dataframe to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowwise` is slow, you should avoid using it if you can. The operation you are doing can be vectorized:

```
v <- c(9,11,33,43,44)
x1 <- x %>% 
           mutate_at(1:5, funs(. %in% v)) %>% 
           filter(rowSums(select(., 1:5)) == 3 & V6 != 13)
```

It's pretty fast even with the large data set you are providing:

```
system.time(x1 <- x %>% mutate_at(1:5, funs(. %in% v)) %>% filter(rowSums(select(., 1:5)) == 3 & V6 != 13))

#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.561   0.807   4.465
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to also keep the original data in filtered data.frame?

Comment: You can create new variables instead of replacing the original ones by providing a suffix inside `mutate_at..funs`, and later on select based on the suffix of the columns. such as `x %>% mutate_at(1:5, funs(bool = . %in% v)) %>% filter(rowSums(select(., ends_with("bool"))) == 3 & V6 != 13)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` as well to make it faster

```
library(data.table)
v <- c(9,11,33,43,44)
setDT(x)[x[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x %in% v))==3 & V6 != 13, .SDcols = 1:5]]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
library(fastmatch)
system.time(setDT(x)[x[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(fmatch(x, v))))==3
         & V6 != 13, .SDcols = 1:5]])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.75    0.92    4.68
```